# oracle datetime group by

Tags: oracle

I want to group data based on date time in oracle 
eg:-

```
03-DEC-13 06:12:03:23,
03-DEC-13 06:12:03:25,
04-DEC-13 08:12:03:23,
04-DEC-13 08:12:03:25
```

expected result  :- 03-DEC-13 06:12:03, 04-DEC-13 08:12:03

neglect seconds.

Comment: hi @Vasim Sajad has any of these answers been helpful to solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question. When an answer helped you, can you accept it by clicking the hollow green check mark next to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT trunc(some_date, 'MI') FROM some_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is not completely clear, but I think something like:

```
select to_char(datefield, 'DD-MMM-YY HH24:MI') , count(*) /* or other grouping */
from   table 
group by to_char(datefield, 'DD-MMM-YY HH24:MI')
```

If you want to include date/times for which you don't have a value, use something like join with a calendar table or a join with

```
select  to_date('20000101', 'YYYYMMDD') + level / 24 day_and_hours
from    dual
connect by level <= 100
```

Check your performance when doing so.